# Files referenced in .ASPX not found

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I've created a new web application project in Visual Studio 2008, and then copied in some code from a project created with an older VS version.  For instance, I'll add a new web form item in my project, say, "Shop.aspx".  Then copy the older code into the new file.  The trouble is that referenced supporting files get a "not found" warning.

So, I'll have a line in the .aspx like:

```
<link media="all" href="ShopStyle.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

The file ShopStyle.css resides in the same root folder of my project as Shop.aspx, but I get a "not found" warning about it.  Or I'll have something like

```
<img alt="" src="Images/Navbar/MainLogoImage.gif" height="54"/>
```

Where MainLogoImage.gif is in the "Images/Navbar/" subfolder of my project folder and I get the same warning.

I've made sure that I added all of these existing items into my project in Solution Explorer.  Why aren't they found?

Comment: Are the referenced file found at run-time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried placing the '~' character at the front of the path?  i.e.   ~/ShopStyle.css or ~Images/NavBar/MainLogoImage.gif.... I'm not sure why it does this (perhaps someone could enlighten me) but that has worked for me.

Comment: The tilda `~` only works for server side controls. So you cannot use in a <link> tag or an <img> tag. You could use if you changed the <img> to an <asp:Image>. But you can't use in <link>.